# getting null value in apex controller, when passing parameter from javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller

Hi I am trying to pass a field value from javascript code to apex controller. However I tried to pass value in multiple ways, I am still getting null value in the controller.

Here is my Code:

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="phone" docType="html-5.0" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function myPhone(){
    var phn=document.getElementById("phone").value;
    alert(document.getElementById("phone").value);
}
</script>
    <apex:form >
           <div class='form-group'>
           Enter Phone number here:
               <input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
           </div>
        <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" onclick="myPhone()" value="Submit" id="findPhone" action="{!submit}" Rerender=""/>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public without sharing class phone {

    public PageReference submit() {

        String phone = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('phn');
        system.debug('**********'+phone);
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/apex/FindCustomer?att='+phone);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to pass phone number from vf page to the controller.

Comment: You never assign the phone variable to a parameter.

Comment: You can use actionFunction to pass the value to controller from JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strictly use apex:input instead of apex:inputText, You can use `apex:actionFunction`.

Removed submit action from `apex:commandButton` and added it to action which is being called from JavaScript:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="dummy"/>

<apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" onclick="myPhone()"  
    id="findPhone" 
    action="{!submit}" 
    rerender="dummy"/>    

<apex:actionFunction action="{!submit}" 
    name="submitActionFunction" reRender="">
    <apex:param name="phn" value="dummy"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Invoke the actionFunction from JavaScript which would call your submit method, make sure to pass the parameter:

```
<!-- JavaScript Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myPhone(){
        var phn=document.getElementById("phone").value;
        // alert(document.getElementById("phone").value);

        // calling actionFunction
        submitActionFunction(phn);
    }
</script>
```

Note: You should rerender something, I had expected different issues over the past.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding javaScript variable with apex variable that's why you're getting an error. You can directly bind apex variable to `<apex:inputText>` and and use it in your controller.

From [Component Reference](https://fastandfurious-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp) for `inputText`:

> An HTML input element of type text. Use this component to get user input for a controller method that does not correspond to a field on a Salesforce object.
>   This component doesn't use Salesforce styling. Also, since it doesn't correspond to a field, or any other data on an object, custom code is required to use the value the user enters.
>   This component supports HTML pass-through attributes using the "html-" prefix. Pass-through attributes are attached to the generated  tag.

This can be done without using javaScript.
To send Phone Number from VF page to Controller you should try something like this:

**Visualforce Page**

```
<div class='form-group'>
           Enter Phone number here:
               <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control" id="phone" value="{!phoneNo}" />
           </div>
        <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" value="Submit" id="findPhone" action="{!submit}" Rerender=""/>
```

And your **Controller** should be:

```
public String phoneNo{get;set;}
public PageReference submit() {
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/apex/FindCustomer?att='+phoneNo);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;
    }
```

Comment: I am creating a custom visualforce field, which is not available in the object and couldn't use apex:inputText tag

Comment: @venky `<apex:inputText>` is not bind to any object. You can directly use it by binding any apex variable to it. `<apex:inputField>` are bound to object. See [Component](https://fastandfurious-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp) reference

Comment: @venky, added another answer which is another version as rohit's but which supports apex:input.